# Space Travel Generator

Tags: automation, game, flight-simulator, physics

I'm looking for software with a 3D galaxy / universe that will automatically choose interesting features in space and fly to them for you. It will keep flying to different objects until you stop the program. Something where you have to write your own scripts to accomplish this would be fine as well.

Think something like [SpaceEngine](https://spaceengine.org/) but with a fully automatic exploration mode.

SpaceEngine does have this as a planned feature, but I don't know when the developer will get around to it.

Comment: Just to be clear, it should show on screen what a space traveler would see, right?

Comment: Yes, basically just pretty views of space. If there's some sort of spacecraft interior, that would work too, but the main idea is to see the wonders of the cosmos.